# One-dimensional discrete Fourier Transform in java (rfft)

Tags: python, java, fft

I,m trying to port python code to Java. We need to make Fourier Transform for real input.

The following code already ported and works perfectly:

**Python Code**

```
abs(fft([0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0]))

#output 
array([6, 2.82842712, 2, 2.82842712])
```

**Java Code**
I'm using implementation by code https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/FFT.java.html.

```
int n = 4;
Complex[] x = new Complex[n];

// original data
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    x[i] = new Complex(i, 0);
}
show(x, "x");

// FFT of original data
Complex[] y = fft(x);

// print each y.abs()
// Output the same like python
6.0
2.8284271247461903
2.0
2.82842712474619
```

But i need to compute the one-dimensional discrete Fourier Transform. In python we can make it by function rfft.

```
abs(rfft([0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0]))

#output 
array([6, 2.82842712, 2])
```

Seems I need to get subarray with length =  (n / 2) + 1. But i'm not sure that it's true for all cases.

Question: There is the implemented function rfft in java?

Comment: Can't you just clip `y` to proper size?

Comment: @dedObed I can do it, but I want to be sure that it's correct way.

Comment: yes it is, up to dealing with odd-length inputs, where you'll need n // 2 + 1 outputs. But I guess there should be one around who understands DFT and how it fits into your problem?

Comment: Also, see the original numpy docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html